# How To Have Expo Web Open In A Web Browser With Localhost?

Tags: react-native, vpn, expo, expo-web

Running `npm start` or `expo start` launches the project as follows:

```
React  You can now view My React Native App in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:19006/   On Your Network:  http://157.201.29.49:19006/

Note that the development build is not optimized.

 › To create a production build, run expo build:web  › Press Ctrl+C to exit.

 Expo  Press ? to show a list of all available commands.
```

Launching the Expo web by pressing ‘w’ opens Chrome browser with the IP address URI `http://157.201.29.49:19006/` as advised.

However because of the office VPN, Chrome browser fails to resolve the address. The error is:

> This site can’t be reached
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Replacing the URL in Chrome with http://localhost:19006 succeeds.

How can I start Expo such that pressing ‘w’ automatically launches with localhost rather than the IP address?

Comment: expo start then open in chrome :  http://localhost:19002/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix, launch `expo` directly as follows supplying the localhost option:

```
expo start —-localhost
```

See [Expo CLI docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/expo-cli/) for `expo start`:

```
--localhost Same as --host localhost
```

Comment: expo start was helpful thank you

Answer (score 6):

It is no longer supported.

> Update July 25, 2022: expo-cli@6.0.0 has been released with the web UI
> removed. The last release to include the web UI is expo-cli@5.5.1.

[learn more](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206)

Comment: Thank you for this I was so confused

Answer (score 2):

```
expo start --web
```

or

```
npm run web
```